# call ASP.net 1.1 service in asp.net using Jquery

Tags: web-services, jquery, asp.net-1.1

I am trying to call ASP.net 1.1 service in asp.net using Jquery, can't figure put what I am doing wrong here, Pleaseeeee help

Javascript Method

```
function YesCheckChanged(vSRID) {
    var para = {
        SRID: vSRID
    };

    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: serviceUrl + "/YesRdoClicked",
        dataType: "xml",
        data: para,
        contentType: "application/xml; charset=utf-8",
        success: function(data, status) {
            alert(data);
            edata = $(data).find("string").text();
            alert(edata);
        },
        error: function(e, status) {

            alert(status);
        }
    });

}​
```

Error

> System.InvalidOperationException: Request format is invalid:
>   application/xml; charset=utf-8.
>   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.HttpServerProtocol.ReadParameters()
>   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandler.CoreProcessRequest()

Service method Code

```
[WebMethod(true)]       
public string YesRdoClicked(int SRID)
{
    clsEntity obj = new clsEntity();
    obj.New_DeleteTempEntity(SRID);
    return "yes";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1231/ASP-NET-Web-Service

I finally resorted to native Activex calls as no other way seem to work for me. Personally I wanted to avoid using it. But It works well.

A word of caution here, activeX are not very well supported in browsers other than IE so you need to either have IE Only application or convince the client to upgrade to higher version of asp.net.